# count and sort in cgridview getValidators error

Tags: yii

I'm getting an error when i add in STAT. I'm trying to count the number of responses for each user and sort it from desc order.
My error: CActiveDataProvider and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getValidators".

relation:
`'stickerCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'UserSticker', 'user_id'),`
controller:

```
$likes=new CActiveDataProvider('UserSticker');

$this->render('index',array(
    'likes'=>$likes,
        'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'stickerCount DESC',
        ),
));

<?php
$this->widget ( 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array (
        'id'=>'follower',
        'type'=>'striped condensed',
        'dataProvider'=>$likes,
        'filter'=>$likes,
        'columns'=> array(
'stickerCount',
)));
?>
```

Comment: You cannot use STAT relation fields in sort. For that to work you need to add a subquery into your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->join = 'JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) As stickerCounter '
            . 'FROM user_sticker GROUP BY user_id) userSticker '
            . 'ON userSticker.user_id = t.id';

$likes = new CActiveDataProvider('MainTable',array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));

...
```

Comment: Okay, but I'm still getting error CActiveDataProvider and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getValidators". In my gridview do I just get stickerCounter?

Comment: Can you post your view file?